# Game Theory number of ways to win in a sequential game

Tags: game-theory

two players start with **a** and **b** points.  In each set of the game, they can score a point from **-k to k** (both including). if **s** set are played, the number of ways the first player can win the game.

So in every set there are **4*k^2** ways, for example in the first set point can end up in for the first player **[a-k, a+k]** and for second player **[b-k,b+k]**

Comment: How are points distributed? Does the winner of a round gain a point and the loser lose a point? Is it possible for both to gain or both to lose points in a given round?

Comment: yup, it is based on probability

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't answer my question. I need to know whether in a round the winner always gains a point and the loser always loses a point and if it's possible for 1) no one to gain or lose points 2) both to gain or lose points. You're going to need to edit your question to get the help you want.

Comment: edited, 1) yes it's possible 2) yes it's possible